# Determine if a static method is purely functional

Tags: java, reflection, purely-functional

Given a `java.lang.reflect.Method` object, is there anyway to determine whether the method is purely functional (i.e., given the same input, it will always produce the same output and it is stateless. In other words, the function does not depend on its environment)?

Comment: Why don't you test it with a unit test? Fill it with random data and see what happens. How do you want to retrieve this result?

Comment: You are hard pressed to find a 100% effective solution

Comment: Please clarify: Why are you doing this? Do you own all the code that you intent to apply this testing? Do you want to test any external (api) code?

Comment: Imagine you are writing an API fucntion that takes a Method object and returns a boolean indicating whether the method is purely functional.

Comment: Do you own all the code that you intent to apply this testing?¹

Comment: Yes, I do. Hmm.. why?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but asking to see if someone with more expertise can help. Would it be possible to take just the code from the function and put it into a VM where it had no security permissions to affect application state? Again I don't know enough about things like SecurityManager, so this may be completely undoable.  But the idea is generally to put the code into an isolated container (VM, etc.), that enforces the rules needed, and see if any violations occur.

Comment: wouldn't it be equivalent to the halting problem?

Comment: So if you own all the code you're testing, why don't you know whether it's functional or not?

Comment: If you do own all the code you intent to test, go with @SotiriosDelimanolis approach. Just add an annotation (or configure somehow somewhere) if the methods are functional or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there's no way to do it.

Reflection does not allow you to inspect the actual code behind the method.

And even if that where possible, the actual analysis would probably be ... tricky, to say the least.

Comment: Do you happen to know of any paper that discussed the computability of this kind of problem? And thanks for the answer.:)

Comment: @OneTwoThree: nope, don't know of that. Intuitively I'd say you're running close to halting-problem area here, but practically you can probably get pretty far by allowing "don't know" and treating it as no (in other words: a few simple heuristics will probably work for most positive cases).

Answer (score 7):

No there is no way to do that with reflection or any other mechanism.

The developer knows if the method is functional. For example, Spring has a [`@Cacheable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) annotation that gives a hint to the application that the method is functional and can therefore cache the result for a given set of arguments. (Spring will wrap your object in a proxy that provides the caching behavior.)

Comment: +1 I was about to comment something like "make the dev add an annotation".

Comment: I think that this applies to a very short set of scenarios, given that he would need to control all the code he intends to check. But if the OP does have that control, yes it's effective. Also, this relies on what it's being said about the method (the annotation), not what it really does.

Comment: @EvertonAgner You can apply caching without the annotation, but with AOP config. The document linked explains the configuration required.

Answer (score 0):

> is there anyway to determine whether the method is purely functional(ie., given the same input, it will always produce the same output

I know it's now what you've asked for, but Unit Tests **may** help you with this.

Comment: But only if you can properly define what "the environment" is so that you can create all possible scenarios in which you can change something in it to see if that change influences the method / static function. Otherwise even by throwing unit tests at it, you still can't know with reasonable certainty.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. But if you can indeed load an entire "test" environment for the unit tests, probably this will be very effective.

Comment: What if I am writing an API that takes a method as its input and return a boolean?

Comment: You would probably just test N times the method with it's parameter and then check if the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

No. Reflection can not read the byte code of the method. So you can't really tell what a method does or even what other classes it uses.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection will not help you here. If you *really want* to define it at run time, you can try to use `javap -c classname.class`. But it would be better to avoid such a hacks.